# How to search for keywords in the user input python 3

Tags: python-3.x

I am 15, to start, and I am attempting to self learn how to code.

I've been working on a system for some time now and I've made some progress by using other examples to learn, but I can't find a guide that I can quite learn from.

Basically, I want to write a code that can search for specific key words in the user input. I have found areas of this where you set a variable to these keywords and it finds where one of them is and if one of them is it prints a function.

```
hi = ['hi', 'hello', 'Hi', 'Hello', 'sup', 'Sup', 'howdy', 'Howdy', 'hey', 'Hey']
bye = ['bye', 'Bye', 'Goodbye', 'goodbye', 'Power Down', 'power down', 'Power Off', 'power off']
shut_down = 0

while shut_down < 1:
  user_input = input("Input: ")
  for element in user_input:
    if element in hi:
      import random
      greeting = random.sample(['Hello there.', 'Howdy partner', 'It is nice to talk to you.', 'Hi friend.', 'Sup mah human!'], 1)
      print (greeting)
    elif element in bye and not hi:
      import random
      farewell = random.sample(['Goodbye friend.', 'Goodbye', 'Farewell', 'See you later', 'Bye bud', 'Thanks for talking with me.'], 1)
      print(farewell)
      shut_down = int(shut_down) + 1
```

I am planning on adding more to the key words to allow for even more responses to eventually develop a conversation, but this system doesn't run properly as is.

Answer (score 0):

Please provide a better example.
From what I understand, 
you can use a list of keywords.

```
key_w = ['word1','word2','word3','etc.']
```

Then ask the user for input and search for keywords.

```
userIn = input('Input: ')
for element in userIn:
    if element in key_w:
        function_that_does_AI()
```

Then, based on the chronology of the keywords, the function can interpret it.